# Best way to validate a float value between 0 and 5

Tags: python

I want to validate a float value between 0 and 5 that can have the format x.xx

So `3.14` is valid, however `3.14a` would be invalid.

```
if x <= 0 or x > 5 or not x.isdigit():
    return 'error'
```

However, this will return error for 1.1, since there's the `'.'` character...

Answer (score 3):

```
def is_valid(num):
    try:
        return 0 < float(num) <= 5
    except ValueError:
        print('error: not a valid floating point number')
        return False
```

`float` will raise a `ValueError` if `num` is not a number which can be interpreted as float.

Comment: I have added a `try`/`except` block to handle the case you mention. Please feel free to roll back the edit if you do not agree with or like that modification

Comment: Since I don't think that returning `'error'` is a great error handling way exactly I'd have left the exception in place and leave the correct error handling up to the caller... but it illustrates the point better.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex:

```
import re

validate = lambda x: re.match(r"^[0-4]\.[0-9]{2}|5\.00$", x) is not None
x = "1.21"

if not validate(x):
    print('error')
```

This will match a string containing a number with the `y.xx` format, where `y` is in the `0-4` range and `y` can be any. This covers the `0.00-4.99` range. Finally, we cover `5.00` as a special case.

If you need to accept `4.0` as well, you can slightly modify the regex as

```
r"^[0-4]\.[0-9]{1,2}|5\.00?$"
```

so that the second digit becomes optional.

Comment: What about a value of `5.99`?

Answer (score 1):

```
x = "3.14a"
try:
    if float(x) <= 0 or float(x) > 5:
        print('error')
except:
    print('error')
```

I think isinstance will solve your problem

Comment: I think in OP's case `x` is a `str` not a `float`. You could possibly use `try float(x): except ValueError:` kind of a thing

Comment: Overly complicated. How could `float(x)`not be an instance of `float`?

Answer (score 1):

```
def is_string_a_float_between_0_and_5(s):
    try:
        return 0 <= float(s) <= 5
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert your string to a float. If it fails *that* test then you know you don't have a number. If it converts, then you can check if it is between 0 and 5:

```
x = '3.14'
try:
    x = float(x)
except ValueError:
    return 'error'

if x <= 0 or x > 5:
    return 'error'
```

If `x` is '3.14a' then it will hit the `ValueError` and return `'error'`

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a bit of information here. Are you expecting that `x` is a string? If that's the case, you need to cast `x` to a float before testing if it's between 0 and 5.

Secondly, it's considered "non-pythonic" to check your variable types. Python is a "duck typed" language, and you're not supposed to check types unless absolutely necessary. [Here's a great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6589967/how-to-handle-duck-typing-in-python) about if someone misuses your function.

To answer the real question about checking if a number is between 0 and 5:

```
y = float(x)  # Will throw exception if x is not castable to a float
if y < 0 or y > 5:
    raise ValueError("Bad x parameter!")
```